# Omit extra parameters on the Redirect URI

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I am implementing an Oauth2 auth server using Spring. After authentication I need to generate an JWToken with some extra information in it.

I have an *AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter* configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class AuthServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    //extra code omitted

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("angular")
            .secret(passwordEncoder().encode("the_secret"))
            .autoApprove(true)
            .scopes("")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("implicit", "password", "refresh_token")
            .redirectUris("http://localhost:4200");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(manager)
                .accessTokenConverter(new CustomJwtTokenEnchancer())
                .tokenStore(tokenStore());
    }

}
```

My *CustomJwtTokenEnhancer* will add some information about the user profiles:

```
public class CustomJwtTokenEnhancer extends JwtAccessTokenConverter {
    //extra code omitted

    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(
            OAuth2AccessToken accessToken,
            OAuth2Authentication auth) {

        final Map<String, Object> additionalInfo = new HashMap<>();
        additionalInfo.put("profiles", authService.getProfiles(auth.getName()));
        additionalInfo.put("activeProfile", authService.getActiveProfile(auth.getName()));

        ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken).setAdditionalInformation(additionalInfo);

        return super.enhance(accessToken, authentication);
    }
}
```

The token generation is ok but the redirect URI will have all the extra information as parameters:

```
localhost:4200/#access_token={token}&token_type=bearer&expires_in=21599&scope=&profiles=%5B200022032,%201786154,%201616954,%201666754%5D&activeProfile=1666754&jti=e0677289-94a5-47da-a00e-b63c3d4c0598
```

This is a problem because some users have a lot of profiles and due to these cases I needed to increase the max-http-header-size.

As it is duplicated information I would really like to omit it from the URI. Is there any way to achieve that?